# Generate UUID on Ebean @Entity

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two fields in my User class

```
@Id
@Column(name="revisionId", length=36, updatable=false)
private UUID revisionId;

@Column(name="userId",length=36, updatable=false)
private UUID userId;
```

On insertion, I would like the userId (which is not a primary key of the table) to be generated as a UUID, using annotations.

I've looked up and down play-framework / ebean documentation and can not find a way to do this with annotations, but I feel like it should be pretty basic.

Comment: Have you also looked at this: https://github.com/jamesward/play2-ebean-uuid ?

Comment: Yes, I have. What in particular are you referring to in that code repo that would help me? That's just a repository code from the previous play introduction video tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ebean doesn't support multiple auto generated fields. The reason for this is that neither the relational model nor the object model allows you to have multiple auto-generated keys. An example of this is trying to have multiple auto-increments in a table or multiple time-stamp.

In order to accomplish what you are trying to do, you'll have to either create your own annotation or annotate your entity to generate a UUID on PrePersist.

Please note that in play you'll have to first specify a listener class to handle those annotation in your application.conf.

```
ebean.default="models.*, models.sgcore.SGBeanPersistController"
```

Please view the following gist as an example of a Listener. 
https://gist.github.com/domdorn/1547244